# Separation of Runtime and History

Tags: camunda

I whould like to use separate databases for runtime and history data without implementing a custom HistoryEventHandler. Does someone know how this is possible?

I read the camunda user guides but this did not help much because it only hints the custom implementation way.

Currently, everytime I query history data (about 2mil activity entries) the performance of the system drops as it kind of blocks the runtime, too. I'd like to avoid this without loosing the ability to query historic data.

Answer (score 0):

Camunda BPM offers Optimize, which pulls the history data from the Engine to an Elastic Search database. If you are using the Enterprise version, it may be a way to solve it.

Comment: Hi, thx for the hint. I do have the enterprise version, I'll search for optimize. However I still whould like to see a mention by "just" configuring a second database for the history. :)

Comment: optimize is not part of the standard enterprise edition, it has to be licenesed separately

Comment: thx for clarification, so that won't be an option for my employer I'm afraid. Thx for the info anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

That would be a really cool feature, but it is currently not supported. You will have to disable the default history and implement a custom handler.

Comment: Do you have some experience with it or can point me to some guidance? I'd like to know which parts I need to exchange besides the event handler so it feels like it whould be the default..

Answer (score 0):

(Based on your comments to other answers, it appears that you're interested in learning more about custom HistoryEventHandler implementations. Thus, I'm adding this answer in the hope that it will help.)

Implementing a custom History Event Handler isn't difficult, but there are a few important points to keep in mind:

- Unless you want to skip the storage of history information in the standard Camunda history tables, you'll want to use their CompositeHistoryEventHandler. This simply gives you the ability to use multiple HistoryEventHandler implementations.
- Any HistoryEventHandler implementations will complete in the same threads as the ones executing process instances; thus, you will want to be cognizant of the performance impacts your custom HistoryEventHandler will have.
- You may want to consider publishing your history events through a message bus or messaging system to allow for reliable delivery without impacting Camunda workflow instance performance.
- Finally, it may make sense to use your custom HistoryEventHandler along with Camunda's default HistoryEventHandler and their functionality for deleting process instances after a period of time. This would allow you to use their querying capabilities for some period of time without having the history stack up (and thus slowing down your system).